# how can I connect my crystal report into network

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

This is my Code, when I am opening my crystal report its always giving me a form that is need to fill username and password. I want to disable It. Another problem is when I installed my project in my Computer, my project correctly running but still need to fill user and password, and if I installed to a network or other computer, when I fill the user and password same in local host its give me an error.

Private Sub AssignConnection(ByVal rpt As ReportDocument)
        Dim connection As New ConnectionInfo()

```
    connection.DatabaseName = "pcba_info" 
    connection.ServerName = "192.168.0.201" 
    connection.UserID = "partschecker" 
    connection.Password = "sgic" 

    For Each table As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In rpt.Database.Tables
        AssignTableConnection(table, connection)
    Next

    ' Now loop through all the sections and its objects to do the same for the subreports
    '
    For Each section As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section In rpt.ReportDefinition.Sections
        ' In each section we need to loop through all the reporting objects
        For Each reportObject As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportObject In section.ReportObjects
            If reportObject.Kind = ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject Then
                Dim subReport As SubreportObject = DirectCast(reportObject, SubreportObject)
                Dim subDocument As ReportDocument = subReport.OpenSubreport(subReport.SubreportName)

                For Each table As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In subDocument.Database.Tables
                    AssignTableConnection(table, connection)
                Next

                subDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(connection.UserID, connection.Password, connection.ServerName, connection.DatabaseName)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(connection.UserID, connection.Password, connection.ServerName, connection.DatabaseName)
End Sub


Private Sub AssignTableConnection(ByVal table As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table, ByVal connection As ConnectionInfo)
    ' Cache the logon info block
    Dim logOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo

    connection.Type = logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Type

    ' Set the connection
    logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connection

    ' Apply the connection to the table!

    table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = connection.DatabaseName
    table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = connection.ServerName
    table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = connection.UserID
    table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = connection.Password
    table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Type = connection.Type
    table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo)
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to do? "The network" does not make sense in this context.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I edited my comment. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

try it out

---

Public Sub LogOnToDatabase(ByRef pCrystalReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument)

```
    Dim objTableLogonInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo

    '\ Report objects
    Dim objDatabaseTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
    Dim objCrSection As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section
    Dim objCrReportObject As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportObject
    Dim objCrSubreportObject As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.SubreportObject
    Dim objCrSubreport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

    '\ Call you code to get the connection info from the INI or txt file
    objTableLogonInfo = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    objTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "UserID " ' UserIDFromFile
    objTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "Password " ' PasswordFromFile
    objTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ServerName " ' ServerNameFromFile
    objTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DatabaseName " ' DatabaseNameFromFile


    '\ Loop through the tables in the database and set the connection properties of each
    For Each objDatabaseTable In pCrystalReport.Database.Tables
        objDatabaseTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(objTableLogonInfo)
    Next objDatabaseTable

    '\ Now do the same for the subreports(if any)
    '\ Loop through the sections in the report
    For Each objCrSection In pCrystalReport.ReportDefinition.Sections

        '\ Loop through the collection
        For Each objCrReportObject In objCrSection.ReportObjects

            '\ If the report object is a subreport
            If objCrReportObject.Kind = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject Then

                '\ Get a reference to it
                objCrSubreportObject = objCrReportObject

                '\ Open it
                objCrSubreport = objCrSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(objCrSubreportObject.SubreportName)

                '\ Set logon info for each table in the subreport
                For Each objDatabaseTable In objCrSubreport.Database.Tables
                    objDatabaseTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(objTableLogonInfo)
                Next objDatabaseTable

            End If
        Next objCrReportObject
    Next objCrSection
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add more description and/or information about your answer (possibly point out which part that has to be edited) and how it solves the asked problem so others can easily understand it without asking for clarification